# Is sticky sessions are different than cookie based sessions?

Tags: session, cookies, cloud

I was wondering that session management in cloud environments are available in many options for Microsoft azure/ Amazon Web Services / any private cloud. What I was looking that which is the best session management technique which will fit in all the cloud environments.

I have gone through many site but could not decide which is the most suitable in all cases. I read somewhere that Sticky sessions are also one of the option for session management. So looking for an answer which states that **is Sticky sessions are different from cookie based session management?**

If yes then how to use it?

Thanks 
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky session are likely to stay on same server when the first request comes and provided from same server for each request. Where as cookie based session are nothing but keeping the data on client machine in browser. can be served from any server which is available.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sticky Sessions are different than cookie based sessions.

As sticky sessions are nothing but handled by load balancers which handles to get sessions in request from client and passes it to the same server where the first request came to that server. E.g. While loading an website request goes to server A, then sessions get stored on server A, while next request comes from user the request sent to the same server i.e. Server A, irrespective of how many servers present in the farm.

Whereas cookie based sessions are stored on client machine, and it gets added with each new request. So it can be read and supported on any server in farm irrespective which server generated and stored session while first login.